# JS - go throught a text, make array entry after each "."

Tags: javascript, string-search, split

I'm new to JavaScript. I have a text with several sentences and I want each sentence to be an entry in a array named sentences and alert("new entry was made"). So I have to loop through and whenever there is a "." a new entry would start. But How can I go through a text till its end?

```
var sentences = []
var myText= "I like cars. I like pandas. I like blue. I like music."
```

Comment: Would [`.split(".")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) do it?

Comment: What if `myText = "I like cars which cost $19000.00. I like pandas";`?  Or `myText = "Mr. Brown likes pandas. I like Mr. Brown.";`

Comment: "*go through a text till its end*" - how do you want to go through it, iterate it character by character or what?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I think such cases are out of the scope of this question, OP wants to learn about basic JS string functions.

Comment: @Bergi If it's purely academic then maybe out of scope. But if this is for an actual implementation, it needs to be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by splitting `myText` on `". "` and then trimming and adding back the full stop.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/gtjxy/2/)

```
var myText = "I like cars. I like pandas. I like blue. I like music."
var sentences = myText.split(". ");
for (var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    if (i != sentences.length - 1)
        sentences[i] = sentences[i].trim() + ".";
}
```

Splitting the text on `". "` instead of on `"."` will mean it will work on sentences like `"That costs $10.50."`

Comment: ThankYou very much @Daniel and thank youfor the jsFiddle, it is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.charAt(index)`.

```
var sentences = [""];
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++){
    var current = myText.charAt(i);
    sentences[count] += current;
    if(current == "."){
        count++;
        sentences[count] = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`

```
var myText= "I like cars. I like pandas. I like blue. I like music.";
var sentences  = myText.split(".");
```

Answer (score 1):

While @Pietu1998's answer shows you how to loop through the characters of a string, the more comfortable way of getting an array of sentences from such a string is by [matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var myText= "I like cars. I like pandas. I like blue. I like music.";
var sentences = myText.match(/\S[^.]*\./g) || [];
```

Of course this just splits the string on every dot, in real-life not every sentence ends with a dot and not every dot terminates a sentence.

Comment: @daisy: Thanks for the hint, I again forgot to type the repeat-`*` :-/